running tensor flow code with specific cpus?
`
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from  keras import datasets, models, layers
from tensorflow.python import kera
(training_images, training_lables), (testing_images, testing_lables) =             datasets.cifar10.load_data()
training_images, testing_images = training_images/255, testing_images/255

class_names = ['Plane', 'Car', 'Bird', 'Cat', 'Deer', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Horse', 'Ship', 'Truck']

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(training_lables[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[training_lables[i][0]])

plt.show()`


I want to run the above code(I'm on a Mac running Big Sur 11), however when I do I get the following message:
2024-05-28 06:11:41.130935: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Is this message trying to tell me that my cpu is not good enough or is it telling me that I need to install more packages to run tensorflow on my cpu?

All it's trying to say is that you could recompile Tensorflow to make it slightly faster. That's a hassle, and probably not worth it. (If you really cared about performance you would be using the Tensorflow GPU version on a beefy Linux system)

Ah. I see. it says though that I need to rebuild with appropriate compiler flags. How would I go about that?
